# How to dynamically add UIComponent into jsf view from managed bean?

Tags: jsf-2

How can I dynamically add UIComponent into JSF view from managed bean
without using JavaScript?

What I want is to simply display additional elements on the page when the response return like inputText when a button is fire.

How can I do this programmatically from JSF manage bean?

Answer (score 1):

You should not add the component dynamically. Simply add it where it belongs, but render it conditionally using the `rendered`-attribute.

```
<ui:inputText value="#{yourBean.text}" rendered="#{yourBean.isRendered}" />
```

You can now use the boolean property `isRendered` in your backing-bean to determine if the `inputText` should be rendered or not. A component that has `rendered="false"` will not appear in the final component-tree, and thus not generate any html-output or other overhead.

Comment: i'm just experimenting. i know that it is not a good solution to render it from the backing bean. But for example i want to add component when just needed,how am i going to achieve that?